# Как просмотреть готовую для запроса строку при query в (pg node js)?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Использую postgresql в node js

```
var pg = require('pg');
```

Вызываю функцию query передавая параметры. Вопрос, а как просмотреть уже скомпилированную строку запроса(с подставленными параметрами), которая отправляется на сервер postgreSql?

```
var query = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = $1::int';
var params = [
    14 // $1
];
dbClient.query(query, params, function(err, result) {

});
```

Comment: Там скорее всего нечто похожее на prepared statements под капотом. Поэтому запрос уйдёт на сервер **в том же виде, что у вас**. А параметры пойдут отдельно. [См. документацию](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/protocol-flow.html#protocol-flow-ext-query).

Comment: А как посмотреть? А то мне ошибку возвращают и пишут место, но непонятно как были вставлены эти параметры в конечный запрос.

Comment: Приложите точное сообщение, тогда будет о чём говорить.

Comment: Ну меня интересует как увидеть сам запрос, по которому выводят ошибку, а не как её исправить. Эту я уже поправил.